# Class Map Generator for Fluent NHibernate

Tags: database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, generator

Is there a Class Map generator for Fluent NHibernate? I need something like db2hbm but I want it to generate Fluent Class Maps instead of xml mappings.

I am aware of AutoMapping for Fluent but that is not what I want. I want to be able to generate Class Map **files** from tables in database and push them to my src repository.

Comment: IMHO if you work in the direction DB->classes you're better off with hbm than fluent-nh. FNH is more intended to *infer your schema* from your classes.

Comment: I c ur point, but in some apps it turns out that u need to go from db->class model (u do not have control over all decisions made) but at the same time u want to have best of two worlds. U want to generate ur domain model classes from db scheme and have ur persistence layer w/ FNH. Tnx for the comment though.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do this with [NHibernate Mapping Generator](https://nmg.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 100 times!! this is an AWESOME open source tool from thought works, So simple and nice to use!!!

Comment: Been looking for quite some time for a tool that's simple and easy to use. Generates POCO's and Mapping file perfectly for fluentNH!

Comment: This generator seems to generate A LOT of extra redundant code that should already be defaults in NHibernate, like specifying 256 as the max length for a string (no need, already default), using `Table("Class")` for Class when it's already the default, etc.  I'm not a big fan of that, the whole point of Fluent NHibernate is that it's supposed to be succinct and readable, but the generator creates a lot of verbose, unnecessary code that's way less readable.

Comment: There is a new version 3 that creates readable maps without the unnecessary defaults.

Comment: I agree with @ColdHawaiian - the code generated is a bit messy but its still much better than typing the classes out by hand. Thanks for the post.

Comment: Very buggy and issue tracker indicates lack of support.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [Visual NHibernate](http://www.slyce.com). Check the Fluent Nhibernate option on the Options screen to create FNH mapping code.

Comment: Do you know any free tool that does the same job?

Comment: As of today, Visual NHibernate is crashy as hell on my not all that complicated DB.

Comment: Without support for VS 2012.  Without support for VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

[LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com) is a great tool that can do this and much more. It´s not free, but it´s worth every cent.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest thing I've come across (T4 Templates example to generate Fluent NH mappings):
http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/SampleFluentNHibernateT4TemplatesCodeGenerationLINQToSQL.aspx